# Qt: What's the difference between remove() and rmdir()

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel, qdir, qmodelindex

```
QFileSystemModel* _dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
.
.

_dirModel->rmdir(index);

_dirModel->remove(index);
```

"rmdir" seems to be made for removing directories, but I succesfully deleted directory with "remove" as well. What's the point of having "rmdir" while "remove" can do the same job?

Comment: Documentation doesn't state that `QFileSystemModel::remove()` can delete directories; only files.

Comment: meaning `rmdir` might fail if there are files in the directory

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist no they are not, you are pointing at *index* in the model.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#remove) :

- `QFileSystemModel::remove` deletes the given file from the file system
- `QFileSystemModel::rmdir` deletes the given directory from the file system.